# How different can one manifold with two different connections on it be?

Tags: differential-geometry, general-relativity

I am taking general relativity and we recently introduced connections and curvature. In the definition of the curvature tensor, the lecture notes said:

"A manifold $M$ with a given affine connection is curved if $R(X,Y)Z$ is not identically zero. If $R(X, Y)Z = 0 $ for all vector fields $X, Y, Z$, then the **connection** is flat."
[emphasis mine]

When I asked, my professor said that it is the manifold that is flat and not the connection, but I have seen other references also say that it is the *connection* that is flat. What is it that is flat? Is it the connection or the manifold, or is it both (together)?

How different can one manifold with two different connections be, can you choose a connection on a given manifold as to make the curvature tensor identically zero? Intuitively it seems a manifold that is curved should always be curved in some sense, but on the other hand it seems that you have a very large freedom in defining the connection. For example if you have a space with two different metrics, the geometry can be very different.

Comment: This is the connection that is flat, but not all manifolds carry a flat connection. Sometimes, we refer to a flat manifold as a manifold which can carry such a flat connection, and even more often, when they are endowed with such a connection

Comment: I see, thank you for the answer! If you take for example $S^2$, is there any way of choosing the connection such that it is flat?

Comment: No, a sphere of dimension $>1$ cannot have a flat affine connection.

Comment: But in the case of a Lie group, you can have a connection that is flat (all the geometry is in the torsion) even if the obvious invariant Levi-Civita connection is quite curved. Try $SO(3)$.